# Retrieve connected rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, crud

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| AccountId    | AccountIdAssociated |
+--------------+---------------------+
| 2            | 3                   |
| 3            | 15                  |
| 1            | 30                  |
| 3            | 12                  |
| 12           | 10                  |
| 10           | 50                  |
| 19           | 32                  |
| 18           | 33                  |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see accounts 2, 3, 10, 12, 15, and 50 are connected to each other either directly or transitively how can I retrieve all these connected `AccountIds` by using only one number (let's say `AccountId = 2`)

Comment: The only question you really appear to ask here is very broad, what are you **specifically** asking here? What have you got and why isn't it working? (*Also, why are you users only male?*)

Comment: I edited the question to be specific

Comment: What are need is a recursive common table expression.

Comment: thanks @Larnu How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here are a couple of rCTEs to "traverse" the hierarchical data:

```sql
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(2 ,3 ),
                (3 ,15),
                (1 ,30),
                (3 ,12),
                (12,10),
                (19,32),
                (18,33))V(AccountID,AccountIdAssociated)),
rCTEUp AS(
    SELECT V.AccountID,
           V.AccountIdAssociated
    FROM VTE V
    WHERE V.AccountID = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT V.AccountID,
           V.AccountIdAssociated
    FROM VTE V
         JOIN rCTEUp r ON V.AccountIdAssociated = r.AccountID),
rCTEDown AS(
    SELECT V.AccountID,
           V.AccountIdAssociated
    FROM VTE V
    WHERE V.AccountID = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT V.AccountID,
           V.AccountIdAssociated
    FROM VTE V
         JOIN rCTEDown r ON V.AccountID = r.AccountIdAssociated)
SELECT AccountID,
       AccountIdAssociated
FROM rCTEUp
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountID,
       AccountIdAssociated
FROM rCTEDown
WHERE AccountID != 3;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221600/discussion-on-answer-by-larnu-retrieve-connected-rows-in-sql-server).